App redirects to Power BI when embedding protected Power BI report in React
I am creating a react application which embeds a Power BI report. I followed the steps outlined in the official docs for embedding a Power BI report. Setup a new Azure AAD tenant and granted all the relevant permissions on Azure Portal and Power BI.
I have implemented user identity authentication using MSAL for my app to authenticate users and generate access token for requesting the report. Also using powerbi-client-react package to embed the report using PowerBIEmbed component.
When I embed the report in my application since its protected it asks the users to request permission from the report author to view the report. If they have the required permission the report loads in my app without any issues. But if the users don't have access it prompts them to create a account by redirecting to Power BI and request access from Power BI.
Now every user using my application might not want to create a Power BI account to view the report but since the report is protected the report requires permission before viewing the report. How can I find a solution for this issue.
I have tried researching online forums for a solution to this problem, I am yet to find a suitable solution for this. The only solution that works is that the Power BI report needs to be public so it loads in the app but that is not ideal.

Could you please clarify whether you are using a service principal or a master user scenario for authentication?
Additionally, it would be helpful to know how you are currently obtaining the access token for requesting the report. Are you acquiring the access token through user authentication using MSAL, or are you utilizing a service principal or master user for this purpose?
